# Google Managed SSL Certificate Domain Stuck on FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I've been working on this issue for a while now. I'm using terraform code to deploy a static website in GCS. The domain is registered in Cloud Domains and the DNS records are handled in Cloud DNS. I am using terraform to deploy everything I need. The issue here is that the SSL certificate never finishes provisioning, because the domains (kade-bc.com and [www.kade-bc.com](http://www.kade-bc.com)) both have the status FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE.

It's worth noting that my HTTP connection works fine, it's just the HTTPS certificate generation that is the issue. I'm fairly new to this so I could be overlooking something but I've looked at similar questions here and was not able to resolve my issue. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my relevant terraform code:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  name          = "the-site-bucket"
  location      = "US"
  force_destroy = true

  website {
    main_page_suffix = "index.html"
    not_found_page   = "404.html"
  }

  uniform_bucket_level_access = true

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "html_file" {
  name   = "index.html"
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.my_bucket.name
  source = "../site/index.html"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "css_file" {
  name   = "styles.css"
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.my_bucket.name
  source = "../site/styles.css"
  content_type = "text/css"
  metadata = {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_global_address" "website" {
  provider = google
  name     = "website-lb-ip"
}

resource "google_dns_managed_zone" "my_dns_zone" {
  name     = "my-zone"
  dns_name = "kade-bc.com."
}

resource "google_dns_record_set" "website" {
  provider     = google
  name         = google_dns_managed_zone.my_dns_zone.dns_name
  type         = "A"
  ttl          = 300
  managed_zone = google_dns_managed_zone.my_dns_zone.name
  rrdatas      = [google_compute_global_address.website.address]
}

resource "google_dns_record_set" "www_record" {
  provider     = google
  name         = "www.${google_dns_managed_zone.my_dns_zone.dns_name}"
  type         = "A"
  ttl          = 300
  managed_zone = google_dns_managed_zone.my_dns_zone.name
  rrdatas      = [google_compute_global_address.website.address]
}

# Create HTTPS certificate
resource "google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate" "website" {
  provider = google
  name     = "website-cert"
  managed {
    domains = [google_dns_record_set.website.name, google_dns_record_set.www_record.name]
  }
}

# Add the bucket as a CDN backend
resource "google_compute_backend_bucket" "website" {
  provider    = google
  name        = "website-backend"
  description = "Contains files needed by the website"
  bucket_name = google_storage_bucket.my_bucket.name
  enable_cdn  = true
}

# GCP URL MAP
resource "google_compute_url_map" "website" {
  provider        = google
  name            = "website-url-map"
  default_service = google_compute_backend_bucket.website.self_link
}

# HTTPS access
resource "google_compute_target_https_proxy" "website" {
  provider         = google
  name             = "website-target-proxy"
  url_map          = google_compute_url_map.website.self_link
  ssl_certificates = [google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate.website.self_link]
}

# GCP forwarding rule for HTTPS
resource "google_compute_global_forwarding_rule" "default" {
  provider              = google
  name                  = "website-forwarding-rule"
  load_balancing_scheme = "EXTERNAL"
  ip_address            = google_compute_global_address.website.address
  ip_protocol           = "TCP"
  port_range            = "443"
  target                = google_compute_target_https_proxy.website.self_link
}

#HTTP access 
resource "google_compute_target_http_proxy" "website_http" {
  provider = google
  name     = "website-target-http-proxy"
  url_map  = google_compute_url_map.website.self_link
}

# GCP forwarding rule for HTTP 
resource "google_compute_global_forwarding_rule" "http" {
  provider              = google
  name                  = "website-forwarding-rule-http"
  load_balancing_scheme = "EXTERNAL"
  ip_address            = google_compute_global_address.website.address
  ip_protocol           = "TCP"
  port_range            = "80"
  target                = google_compute_target_http_proxy.website_http.self_link
}
```

I've waited for the DNS records to propagate, I've checked that the domain resolves to the correct IP using nslookup, I changed my CNAME record ([www.kade-bc.com](http://www.kade-bc.com)) to be an A record pointing to the load balancer, I tested using HTTP (connection works fine). I expect the certificate to provision without issues, but nothing changed and the status is still FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE for the domains.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your HCL by visual review. Your problem is almost always a) an incorrect DNS configuration; b) you have not waited long enough for the records to populate and for Google to issue the certificate. For a DNS configuration problem, you must include the real DNS names, otherwise we cannot test or verify. How long have you waited? Before posting a problem, wait at least 24 hours after your last DNS change before posting a problem here.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, thanks for the response. I've updated the post to include the real DNS names. I deleted and re-applied the configuration ~24 hours ago to see if that was an issue. Before that I had the same configuration that was stuck on the FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE status for 4 days.

Comment: I just posted and then updated my answer. Your Terraform is creating a hosted zone for your domain that is empty (not configured). Do not do that. Instead manually create the hosted zone, update your Registrar settings (per my answer) and rewrite your Terraform to read the hosted zone instead of creating one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a DNS problem.

Neither kade-bc.com or [www.kade-bc.com](http://www.kade-bc.com) are configured correctly or work.

Your Terraform is creating an empty zone for kade-bc.com.

Step 1: Verify the Registrar Settings. Go to [whois](https://www.whois.com/whois/kade-bc.com) and verify the Name Servers.

Output:

```
ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com
```

Go to [Google Cloud DNS](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/dns/zones), and find the DNS name `kade-bc.com`. Click on that record and view the **Routing data**. The servers listed should match the Registrar settings above.

If the Registrar configuration does not match the Google Cloud DNS servers allocated to your hosted zone, then update the Registrar settings at Squarespace Domains. You must wait about 24 hours before testing again.

If the zone does not exist, you will need to create it and then update the Registrar with the correct name server entries. Then wait before testing.

The following link is an excellent tool for testing DNS resource records:

[Google Admin Toolbox Dig](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/)

Problem #2.

Your Terraform HCL is creating the hosted zone. Instead of using the Resource google_dns_managed_zone, you should use the Data Source google_dns_managed_zone. [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/dns_managed_zone)

```
data "google_dns_managed_zone" "env_dns_zone" {
  name = "name-of-zone"
}
```

Comment: Manually creating the hosted zone + DNS records fixed it. Thanks for your help!